# XML handling in Java

Tags: java, xml

Need to select all nodes from the path a/b/c as `NodeList` from a `Document` using `getElementsByTagName()` . How do i provide path of node as input?

eg: -

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>1</c>
            <c>2</c>
            <c>3</c>
            <c>4</c>
            <c>5</c>
            <c>6</c>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

need to select all 'c' nodes from the path a/b/c . How can I achieve this. Directly selecting c is an option, but to avoid ambiguity if more 'c's are present, I need to give the path. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Java [XPathAPI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html). You probably want to specify an XPath of `/root/a/b` to specify all the `<c/>` nodes in the above hierarchy.